# Define picklist values as "selected" in Metadata

Tags: metadata-api, picklist

I deployed some picklist changes, I also made the change in the record type tag:

```
<recordTypes>
   <fullName>FSLead</fullName>
   <active>true</active>
   <businessProcess>FS Lead</businessProcess>
   <compactLayoutAssignment>SF1_Layout</compactLayoutAssignment>
   <description>This is the standard lead page layout for Field Sales</description>
   <label>Field Sales Lead</label>
   <picklistValues>
      <picklist>Disqualified_Reason_s__c</picklist>
        <values>
           <fullName>Competitor contract in effect</fullName>
           <default>false</default>
        </values> 
          ...
```

It works but still some values wind up un-selected and don't show up in the UI, they are still in the available box -->

How can I use metadata to move them from 'available' to 'selected' ?

[image: ta]

Comment: If you have the picklist options defined in the recordtypes tag, it should work ideally.

Comment: You're right, ended up being a merge problem